# How can I create a dialog box using windows scripting?

Tags: windows, scripting

I want to create a dialog box to alert a user when a script is running with an "OK" acknowledgement button.

E.g.:

```
<code to create dialog> "Warning! Back-up process will run in 60 seconds"
```

Can I write something using windows scripting/VBS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty simple. Use the following VB Script

```
WScript.Echo "Warning! Back-up process will run in 60 seconds"
```

[Source: [Wikipedia]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host)

[Documentation: [Microsoft Developer Network]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h8f603s7%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

Comment: documentation lives here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h8f603s7(v=vs.84).aspx